# Query DB with Ajax and Codeigniter (using Bootstrap modal)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Here's a brief description of what I'm trying to achieve: I have an advanced search button that opens a bunch on input fields and select. I have to auto populate the selects with options from the DB, so I have to get the data from there somehow.

Because I don't want to load all the data in the page when it's no need, I want to use AJAX to get the data when the user clicks on the modal button of the advanced search.

I've tried to achieve this using the following code, but nothing really occurs:

View:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnList" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#c_avan">CAUTARE AVANSATA</button>

$('#btnList').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('/admin/date_cautare_avansata'); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            key: value
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller that I try to reach using Ajax:

```
function date_cautare_avansata() {
        $data['items'] = $this->cautare_avansata_model->items();
        $data['major'] = $this->cautare_avansata_model->major();

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

The models are not that important since they work fine. Any idea why this is not working at all? Thanks!

Comment: what you mean by ***Any idea why this is not working at all?***

Comment: The code has no effect, no data is shown in the modal (like an array or anything). I've also tried using alert() to check if it works, and nothing shows up.

Comment: change url to `url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/date_cautare_avansata",`

Comment: On the browsers developer tools network tab, select your request and check the response.

Comment: Post your full html code

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your URL

```
url: '<?php echo site_url('/admin/date_cautare_avansata'); ?>',
     ^                    ^                            ^     ^
```

This should be

```
url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/date_cautare_avansata",
```

Ajax should place inside

`<script></script>`

> and need to call latest **JS Library** too

Comment: fellow ajax order, First Type, then datatype, then url and then data

Comment: ***Hey where is you  `<script>` tag??***

Comment: Changed the order... nothing. I forgot to copy it here, but it's wrapped in a script tag, of course. JS library is called as well...

Comment: what you pass from this `key: value`. and i cant see any use of it

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('#btnList').click(function() {
// Key must have a value. Assign that. 
//Site url no slash in prefix
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/date_cautare_avansata'); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            key: value
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried it, nothing has changed.